Configuring certificates for my vue+nginx+portainer
I have the root folder of the Vue project, which consists of 2 folders backend and frontend with their own dockerfile, docker-compose is at the root. I need to configure it to receive certificates for my domain where the portainer is located. I do not have access to the administrator account in the portainer and I do not have ssh access to the server.  The domain and server with portainer were configured by the system administrator and gave me a username and password to access portainer.  My question is: can I use only portainer to set up certificates for the domain and the operation of my vue application. Now I use http for beck and have access to all the functionality of the application, including the frontend via http://mydomain if I use https, I get an error with certificates. Can I set up automatic receipt and installation of certificates only through the portainer functionality??? I understand that in all files I need to replace http with https, the question is to configure certificates.
My CORS:
app.use(cors({
    origin: [
        'http://mydomain',
        'https://mydomain',
    ]
}));

My vue.app.config (I understand that https needs to be enabled)

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: "source-map"
  },
  devServer: {
    https: false, // Отключаем HTTPS
    host: '0.0.0.0', // Используем 0.0.0.0 для доступа с других устройств в сети
    port: 80 // Укажите порт, который вы хотите использовать
  }
};

My dockerfile for backend:
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3002
CMD ["npm", "start"]

My dockerfile for frontend:
FROM node:18 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

My nginx.conf
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name afishka.pspu.ru;

        location / {
            root /app;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}

My docker-compose:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ***
      POSTGRES_USER: ***
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ***
    volumes:
      - db_data_16:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      -app-network

  backend:
    image: myname/mybackcontainer
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    environment:
      PORT: 3002
      SECRET: ***
      DATABASE_URL: ***
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      -app-network

  frontend:
    image: myname/myfrontcontainer
    container_name: front
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      VUE_APP_SERVER: http://mydomain:3002
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      -app-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ***
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ***
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data_16:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

I tried to add nginx proxy with letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      -app-network

  db:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db1233
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - db_data_16:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - webafishka_app-network

  backend:
    image: myname/mybackcontainer
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    environment:
      PORT: 3002
      SECRET: 'sadfghkjlhdfsa'
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/db1233
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  frontend:
    image: myname/myfrontcontainer
    container_name: front
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      VUE_APP_SERVER: http://mydomain:3002
      VIRTUAL_HOST: yourdomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: yourdomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: your-email@example.com
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data_16:
  certs:
  vhost:
  html:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

with the corresponding variables in my docker-compose, but I received errors with email and the existence of some directories.
I do not fully understand whether I can set up an https connection for my application without contacting the system administrator and additional resources, and whether I need to register with any platforms.
